# Rails how to Get value in Javascript of each object in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

this is my table:

```
<tbody>

<% @productos.each do |producto| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= producto.codigo %></td>
    <td><%= producto.descripcion %></td>
    <td><%= producto.stock %></td>
   <td><%=  button_to '+', "#", method: :get,class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm btn_add' %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>

</tbody>
```

On button click i want to get the value of |producto| (each row)in JAvascript and send to other table in the same view OR the right way is to get the value from td ? example:

```
<td><%= producto.codigo %></td> //in this case how i get the value of this td?
```

Using Javascript or Jquery. thanks

Comment: Show button click handler

Comment: Best way would be to add all the required fields as `data-*` tags to each `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

First add id in every td al follows

```
<tbody>

<% @productos.each do |producto| %>
  <tr>
    <td id="code-<%= producto.codigo %>"><%= producto.codigo %></td>
    <td id="des-<%= producto.codigo %>"><%= producto.descripcion %></td>
    <td id="stock-<%= producto.codigo %>"><%= producto.stock %></td>
   <td><%=  button_to '+', "#", method: :get,class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm btn_add' %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

</tbody>
```

Now in you button add an attribute `data-id` like this

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn_add" data-id="<%= producto.codigo %>" type="button">Click</button>//I don't know about Rails so do this code in your language.
```

Now The jQuery is given below...

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','btn_add',function(){
        id = $(this).data('id'); //get the clicked button's id
        var code = $('#code-'+id).html(); //get the code of that row
        var des = $('#des-'+id).html();  //get the description of that row
        var stock = $('#stock-'+id).html();  //get the stock of that row
        alert('Code - '+code+'<br> Description - '+des+'<br>Stock - '+stock);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- pass all the variable which you want in js code block on click event

```
<td><%=  button_to '+', "#", method: :get,class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm btn_add', :onclick => "get_current_producto(this, '<%=producto.codigo%>', '<%=producto.descripcion%>', '<%=producto.stock%>');"  %></td>
```

2-  get all variables here and

```
<script type="text/javascript>
        function get_current_producto(elm, codigo,descripcion, stock ){
         //code goes here
         //console.log(codigo);
         alert(descripcion);
       };
</script>
```

here `elm` is `button` element on which click event is called you can get id or class of that button element by using `elm`